# find any duplicate element in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.

Note:

Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra memory?

Example 1:

Input: [2,2,1]
Output: 1
Example 2:

Input: [4,1,2,1,2]
Output: 4
```

I found one solution

**Bit Manipulation**
Concept

```
If we take XOR of zero and some bit, it will return that bit
a \oplus 0 = aa⊕0=a
If we take XOR of two same bits, it will return 0
a \oplus a = 0a⊕a=0
a \oplus b \oplus a = (a \oplus a) \oplus b = 0 \oplus b = ba⊕b⊕a=(a⊕a)⊕b=0⊕b=b
So we can XOR all bits together to find the unique number.
```

i tried to implement same approach in javascript like this

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let a = 0
    nums.forEach((i)=>{
        console.log(  a^=i)
        console.log(  a)
        a^=i;
    })

    return a
};

console.log(singleNumber([2,2,1]))
```

but it is not giving correct solution

Comment: Just a note: I would try to be consistent in my code. E.g. no semicolons at the end of all lines. Or function singleNumber(nums) instead of old style.

Comment: Btw this could be a one liner: nums.reduce((a,b)=>a^b)

Comment: The caveat is that one number must appear exactly once and all other numbers, if any, exactly twice. Anything else and the result is meaningless (to me at least). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `a^=i` *twice* on every iteration:

```
nums.forEach((i)=>{
    console.log(  a^=i)
    console.log(  a)
    a^=i;
})
```

As a result, `a`'s bits get switched once, then they get switched back, so the result is always 0.

Remove the first `console.log(  a^=i)`, and it'll work:

```js
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let a = 0
    nums.forEach((i)=>{
        a^=i;
    })

    return a
};

console.log(singleNumber([2,2,1]))
```

More concisely, with `reduce`:

```js
const singleNumber = nums => nums.reduce((a, num) => a ^ num, 0);
console.log(singleNumber([2,2,1]))
```

If you want to log the result of the `^`, use `a ^ i`:

```js
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let a = 0
    nums.forEach((i)=>{
        console.log('a will become:', a ^ i);
        a^=i;
    })

    return a
};

console.log(singleNumber([2,2,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ..!! but still it not giving duplicate item

Comment: The goal is to return the *non-duplicate* item, not the duplicate item. *Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.* So the desired output *should* be 1, and it is, right?

Comment: great anwser ...:)

Answer (score 0):

I think this uses linear runtime complexity, but uses an extra array which uses memory.

```
var f = function(input){
    var input2 = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < input.length; i++){
        if (input2[input[i]])
            input2[input[i]] += 1;
        else
            input2[input[i]] = 1;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < input2.length; i++){
        if (input2[i] == 1)
            return i;
    }

    return input[0];
}
```